# Swagger codegen does not generate models

Tags: openapi, dto, swagger-codegen

I have a api.json as the following format and the pom configuration.

Since I have declared the following line in the pom file,
I am expecting the model(dtoS) generated.
But only
api and invoker package is created.and model is not generated.

How could I provide this?
Thanks.

com.swagger.client.codegen.rest.model

```
"openapi":
"info":
"externalDocs":
"servers":
"paths":
"components": {
  "schemas": {
   ...
  }
}
```

---

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.30</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <language>java</language>
                    <library>resttemplate</library>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.json</inputSpec>
                    <modelPackage>com.swagger.client.codegen.rest.model</modelPackage>
                    <apiPackage>com.swagger.client.codegen.rest.api</apiPackage>
                    <invokerPackage>com.swagger.client.codegen.rest.invoker</invokerPackage>
                    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}</output>
                    <configOptions>
                        <useSwaggerAnnotations>true</useSwaggerAnnotations>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Updated pom dependency:

I have updated my dependency as below an it has generated the model

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.json
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>io.backend.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>io.backend.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>io.backend.invoker</invokerPackage
                            <!-- <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate> -->
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but during generated classes the localTime variable gets error and could not be resolved, how could I resolve this last problem

```
  public EventDtoZoneIdRulesTransitionRules localTime(org.joda.time.* localTime) {
    this.localTime = localTime;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get localTime
   * @return localTime
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")

  @Valid

  **public org.joda.time.* getLocalTime() {**
    return localTime;
  }

  public void setLocalTime(org.joda.time.* localTime) {
    this.localTime = localTime;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

This rest model is the model for openapi 3.0+.

```
"openapi":
"info":
"externalDocs":
"servers":
"paths":
"components": {
  "schemas": {
   ...
  }
}
```

When [OpenApi 3.0 was released](https://www.openapis.org/blog/2017/03/01/openapi-spec-3-implementers-draft-released), it combined the `definitions`, `parameters`, and `responses` section from OpenApi 2.0 into the `components` section that exists in the above model.

You are using version 2.4.30 of the swagger-codegen.  Version 2.X of swagger-codegen [supports Swagger/OpenAPI version 2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#swagger-codegen-2x-master-branch). Version 3.X of swagger-codegen [supports Swagger/OpenAPI version 3](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#swagger-codegen-3x-300-branch).

So, you are generating everything except the models because the generator recognizes the sections of your schema that are the same as OpenAPI 2.0.  However, since it doesn't recognize the `components` section, it is ignoring it.

## Answer

You need to either downgrade your schema to OpenApi V2 or upgrade your generator to V3.  I'd recommend upgrading the generator since it "supports OpenAPI version 3 (and version 2 via spec conversion to version 3)."  This means you can use both OpenAPI versions with the newer generator.